# Windows Batch file to get value of wildcard matched line, check for substring and append string if required

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I'm totally new to command scripting and could use a little direction...

I need to check if a certain line in a .ini file exists, however I only know what part of the line will be. If it exists, I know it will start with the string "Extmgr_Addins=" and it could have any number of comma seperated string values attributed to it.

If I find this line, I need to see if contains the substring "mc". If it does have "mc" already, then do nothing. If it doesn't, I need to append the string ",mc" to the end of that line. This is what i have so far:

```
for /f "TOKENS=*" %%x in (myFile.ini) do (

set line=%%x
set line=!tst:Extmgr_Addins!

if not !line!==%%x ( 
     REM matched string ExtMgr_Addins
   set hasMC = %%x
   set hasMC=!hasMC:mc!

   if not !line!==%%x (

        REM matched substring of mc - do nothing

        )else(

                         REM here is where I would append "mc" to this line                 
        )
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:temploop
(SET tempfile="%temp%\temp%random%.#$#")
IF EXIST %tempfile% GOTO temploop

(FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (myfile.ini) DO (
>%tempfile% ECHO %%x
 FINDSTR /b "Extmgr_Addins=" <%tempfile% >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO.%%x) ELSE (
  FIND "mc" <%tempfile% >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%x,mc) ELSE (ECHO %%x)
 )
)
)>newfile.ini
DEL %tempfile%

ECHO ==== original file =====
type myfile.ini
ECHO ==== modified file =====
type newfile.ini
ECHO ==== differences =====
FC myfile.ini newfile.ini
ECHO ==== end of report =====


GOTO :eof
```

Result:

```
tempfile="c:\temp\temp8291.#$#"
==== original file =====
notthisline
Extmgr_Addins=notargetstring
Extmgr_Addins=mchastargetstring
Extmgr_Addins=hastargetatendmc
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginsnotargetstring
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginsmchastargetstring
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginshastargetatendmc
mcinthisline
thislinehasmctoo
andat the end mc
mc and Extmgr_Addins=
Extmgr_Addins=finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
Extmgr_Addins=mc finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
==== modified file =====
notthisline
Extmgr_Addins=notargetstring,mc
Extmgr_Addins=mchastargetstring
Extmgr_Addins=hastargetatendmc
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginsnotargetstring
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginsmchastargetstring
 Extmgr_Addins=notbeginshastargetatendmc
mcinthisline
thislinehasmctoo
andat the end mc
mc and Extmgr_Addins=
Extmgr_Addins=finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}",mc
Extmgr_Addins=mc finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
==== differences =====
Comparing files myfile.ini and NEWFILE.INI
***** myfile.ini
notthisline
Extmgr_Addins=notargetstring
Extmgr_Addins=mchastargetstring
***** NEWFILE.INI
notthisline
Extmgr_Addins=notargetstring,mc
Extmgr_Addins=mchastargetstring
*****

***** myfile.ini
mc and Extmgr_Addins=
Extmgr_Addins=finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
Extmgr_Addins=mc finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
***** NEWFILE.INI
mc and Extmgr_Addins=
Extmgr_Addins=finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}",mc
Extmgr_Addins=mc finally !@#$%^&*()_+|\=-0<>,./?:;'[]{}"
*****

==== end of report =====
```

The first few lines deal with establishing a valid temporary filename.

We then

1. Read a line
2. dump it into the tempfile
3. Check for the line beginning with the target string
4. If not-found (errorlevel 1) ECHO the line
5. If found (Not errorlevel 1, so errorlevel is 0)

- Check for presence of "mc"
- if not found, output line with ",mc" appended else just output the line

Then delete the tempfile and show a report:
The original MYFILE.INI used
The output NEWFILE.INI
and the differences between them.

Writing the line-under-examination to the tempfile means that awkward characters like `<` and `>` which are redirectors in batch are dealt with properly. The normal method would be to `ECHO %%x|findstr...` but `>` gets stuck in the pipe and leaks out an error message.

About the only problem is that empty lines and possibly lines beginning ';' will be deleted from the output, but lines consisting soleley of spaces will be preserved...

Comment: fantastic work. there's a couple items in there I'll have to research on my own but this should work well. really appreciated. +1